# 3D object viewer in web browsers

Tags: silverlight, flash, html, 3d, mvp

I am looking for a 3D object viewer for my website.

Requirements:

- Files: *.stl,*.wrl, *.3ds *.vrml, *.obj, *.ply, *.skp
- display: models in color and non color
- Unit of Measure: Meters, Centimeter, Millimeters, Inch
- Volume: 3D object viewer has to calculate the orginal size of the model
- Rotation&zoom: user can rotate/zoom with mouse and rotate/zoom by clicking buttons
- Browser: IE& Firefox

[Please take a look at this 3d viewer](http://www.sculpteo.com/en/gallery/order/18592?uuid=fPPDOJcFb1A4435jjds4Af).

Has anybody a idea where I can buy that?

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 2):

i found some, not sure if that what you want though, anyway take a look

http://www.cortona3d.com/Products/Cortona-3D-Viewer.aspx

http://www.geek.com/articles/geek-cetera/a-javascript-3d-model-viewer-in-your-browser-20110129/

http://code.google.com/p/jsc3d/